# remote desktop and local desktop with one desktop only in linux?

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, gnome, mate, xrdp

i setup Ubuntu with xrdp, but the desktop is not the same as windows server offers to a remote users, one desktop.
i need a remote service that allow what microsoft windows server offers with the same desktop and not one local and one remote.
can xrdp, xorgxrdp or vnc do it?
i tried using Gnome for the Local and the remote Mate or both with Gnome and it always giving me to two desktops that aren't the same and not with full options when only one desktop is being used  always with all the options.

Answer (score 0):

i tried with Centos and with centos it working as it should work.
i will try with debian and suse and other distributions so i could see what is the result with each distribution